# How to I substitute my ROW_NUMBER() function using MySql database?

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, sql-server-2012

Here is my query that works fine in either SqlServer or Oracle:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT row_number() over (order by DateTime desc) as RN, Id, DateTime
      FROM MyDbTable
      WHERE Deleted = 'F' AND (Code >= 2) AND (Type LIKE '%stock%') 
     ) t
WHERE RN < 200 AND RN > 100;
```

*Get the Id and Datetime from first 100 rows after the 100th row, ordered by DateTime desc, from MyDbTable where Deleted='F', Code >= 2 and  Type contains the 'stock' string.*

I want to make it run on MySql, but it doesn´t have the row_number() function. How can I accomplish the same results keeping the same structure using MySql ?

Thanks for help.

Comment: Are you using RN in the returned results, or is it simply used to limit and page the results?

Comment: RN is used only to limit page results. No use in application.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
  SELECT Id, DateTime
  FROM MyDbTable
  WHERE Deleted = 'F' AND (Code >= 2) AND (Type LIKE '%stock%')
  order by DateTime desc
  limit 100, 100
```

and if you also need a increasing number:

```
  SELECT Id, DateTime, @rn := @rn + 1  as RN
  FROM MyDbTable
  cross join (select @rn := 0) r
  WHERE Deleted = 'F' AND (Code >= 2) AND (Type LIKE '%stock%')
  order by DateTime desc
  limit 100, 100
```

Comment: This is the one. Though it will perhaps be useful to @Mendez to demonstrate the offset syntax of LIMIT as well.

Comment: What if I need to start from 100 to 200 ? (in reality this is a paging code where the sql is build under some parameters). Check my code update.

Comment: I updated my answer. The syntax is `limit offset, records_to_show`

Comment: This is *tremendously* easy... Why I can´t do that way on Oracle or SQL Server!!! Thanks for help...